# How to list all events a Winforms control is subscribed to

Tags: c#, events, eventhandler

Having searched many of the current articles here on the matter, and trying lots of the code and variations on it, I am still unable to achieve what I want.

In C#, I want to pass a Winforms control to a method and have it return a list of all event handlers of any type that the control has subscribed to. An overload approach would simply return true/false if the control is subscribed to a particular event.

For example:

```
Button btn = new Button() ;

private void  evt(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
private void mevt(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {}

private List<string> GetSubscribedEventList<T>(T item) {}
private bool         CheckEventSubscribed  <T>(T item, string evtName) {}

In Main:

  btn.Click   += new EventHandler(evt) ;
  btn.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(mevt) ;

  List<string> events = GetSubscribedEventList(btn) ;
  bool HasClickEvent  = CheckEventSubscribed  (btn,"CLICK") ;
```

The list method would return a list of items that are the event names of all subscribed events, one event per item in the list.

Obviously, the form of the returned information can be other than a list of strings if some other form is more flexible.

Something like that is what I need. I've tried generating EventHandlerList and using keys and GetInvocationList, but clearly I am not doing it correctly.

Most grateful for assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 => GetEvents(button1).ForEach(ev => MessageBox.Show($"Name: {ev.Name}"));

private List<EventInfo> GetEvents(Control control)
  => control.GetType().GetEvents().ToList();
```

See if it's that what you wanted...

Comment: Thanks. However, that lists all possible events. I want only the subscribed events. So, for example, if a Button has subscribed to two events, Click and MouseHover, I will see only those two events, not all possible events.